# How do I check if the imported component in my return exists in the document with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have a component that returns a different component that has been imported (HelloComponent). In my test I want to check that HelloComponent is in the document.

My component:

```
import HelloComponent from './helloComponent';

const Plans: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
       <HelloComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Plans;
```

My test:

```
describe('plans', () => {

  it('renders the plans component', async () => {
    render(<Plans />);
    // this is where I would check if HelloComponent is in the document. How do I do this?
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about) to find the elements on the page.

Suppose `HelloComponent` renders a text node:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function HelloComponent() {
  return <div>hello</div>;
}
```

You can do that like this:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import Plans from './plans';

describe('plans', () => {
  it('renders the plans component', async () => {
    render(<Plans />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/hello/)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```